# How I can update data inside messageCollectionView cell swift?

Tags: swift, collectionview, messagekit

I would like to show loaded image in the cell. I tried to make it in such way:

```
messages.filter { (mType) -> Bool in
                        mType.messageId == "\(message.id)"
                    }.first?.kind = .photo(ImageMediaItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "photo")!.withTintColor(UIColor.gray, renderingMode: .automatic)))
```

where:

```
var messages = [MessageType]()
```

but I saw a message which said:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'kind' is a get-only property
```

So I decided to add setter/getter to this property:

```
struct Message: MessageType {
    var sender: SenderType
    var messageId: String = ""
    var sentDate: Date
    var kind: MessageKind{
        get {
            return self.kind
        }
        set (newValue) {
            self.kind = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I used such scope for adding data to chat list:

```
messages.append(Message(sender: message.fromId == selectedContactID ? otherSender! : currentUser!, messageId: "\(message.id ?? -1)", sentDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(-8600000), kind: mKind))
```

but after changes mentioned above I saw such message:

```
Extra argument 'kind' in call
```

I tried to look through documentation but I didn't manage to find smth useful for my situation. Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get index of the object you need to change with a `struct`

```
if let index = messages.firstIndex(where:{ $0.messageId == "\(message.id)" }) {
   messages[index].kind = .photo(ImageMediaItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "photo")!.withTintColor(UIColor.gray, renderingMode: .automatic)))
}
```

and for `Extra argument 'kind' in call` a computed property shouldn't be in init in addition to that in your case you don't need to make it `computed property` as you implement what's already exist by default

Comment: So, I can't update certain cell which will have already installed kind inside my collectionview ?

Comment: and your code scope gives me an error `Cannot convert value of type 'MessageType' to expected argument type 'Int'`

Comment: add the index of the object instead of the object itself as a property inside the cell BTW you can delegate everything to the vc to access the array also

Comment: I still can't understand something , I have to change my struct of Message? because after inserting your answer I received message about get only property  :(

Comment: change it to `var kind: MessageKind` or `var kind: MessageKind?` if you need to defer init

Comment: `Type 'Message' does not conform to protocol 'MessageType'` after adding question mark, maybe you can post more info, because I'm a newbie in ios development :)